# How can i make a functionality that uses if statements to switch images based on a random result

Tags: swift, image, if-statement

I have this simple app that is a dice app that has two dice. I want to show a label "JACKPOT!" at alpha(transparency) 1.0 when the user has both dices land with the same number.

Example:
User rolls DiceOne && DiceOne label "jackpot!" changes alpha to 1.0

[image: Example of what i want.]

I tried using an if statement with an array of 5 images of each possible dice number ie: 1,2,3,4,5,6
The code that i wrote worked one day then the next day it no longer works.

```
let dicearray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix")]`

func jackpotShows() {
    if diceImageView1.image == dicearray[0] && diceImageView2.image == dicearray[0] {
        jackpotLabel.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition in your `if` is only true if both dice are ones. Shouldn't it be `if diceImageView1.image == diceImageView2.image`?

Comment: Tromgy thanks for your comment. You made my code MUCH simpler. It works thanks

Comment: But your whole approach is wrong. You should not be comparing _images_. You should _know_ what each dice image represents. Compare data, not views.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement from

```
//This is wrong
if diceImageView1.image == dicearray[0] && diceImageView2.image == dicearray[0] {
        jackpotLabel.alpha = 1.0
    }
```

to

```
//This is right
if diceImageView1.image == diceImageView2.image {
        jackpotLabel.alpha = 1.0
    }
```

Or, alternatively, you could do a for loop:

```
//This is right
for image in diceArray {
    if diceImageView1.image == image && diceImageView2.image == image {
         jackpotLabel.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```